# Git - push from the middle to the top

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm creating a new repository in bitbucket and I want to push from the middle of my history commits to the top, ignoring the first ones. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paraphrase and simplify a bit, you have a repository with a long history (which may include branches and merges omitted from this simplified diagram) that looks something like:

```
A--B--C--...--L--M--N--...--X-Y-Z
```

(where `A` is the very first commit and `Z` is the last so far), but you want a history that looks like:

```
N--...--X-Y-Z
```

i.e., the front half or so of the history (starting from root commit `A`) has been lopped off.

You can't (quite) do that.  Git works on the basis of commits, and each commit has a globally unique ID that depends on the contents of that commit *and* on the entire history leading up to that commit.  In other words, the identity of commit `Z` depends on the existence and identity of commits `A` through `M`.  If you should manage somehow to remove any of these, the identities (the SHA-1s) of every subsequent commit will *change*.

You *can* do this—make new commits with new, different IDs that make a chain starting from (the contents of) `N` and going through `Z`.  They will just all have different IDs from the original `N` through `Z`.  Once you do this, you cannot go back.

As for *how* to do this: there are multiple different ways, but the easiest (if slow) is probably using `git filter-branch`.  The `filter-branch` script makes copies of every commit after applying your supplied filter(s).  So, e.g., if you want to make commit `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890` a root commit:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter \
 'test $GIT_COMMIT = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 && \
  echo "" || cat' -- --all
```

(note that this is untested and filter-branch in general is fairly dangerous and should generally be run on a *copy* [i.e., a clone] of your repository until you work out the filter(s) you really want).  Once the filter-branch finishes you can decide whether you like the result, delete any unwanted branch(es), and then re-clone the filtered repository to ditch objects that are only held on to by filter-branch's `refs/original/` names.

(There are ways to make this faster, and to do this in place, but it sounds like you are very new to git, so it's safer to do all this on a clone that you can simply remove if you don't like the result.  By keeping the original repository untouched, you *can* go back, you just need to resume using the original and stop using the modified clones.)